# Remove elements in Div and Loop until an Element Exists Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm interested if there is a way to remove elements from a div. For example if I had something like this:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I would be interested in removing the div #inner.

Secondly, I know there is a deprecated solution using `DOMNodeInserted` and Mozilla has something similar with `MutationObserver`, but is there a way to look and see if an element exists? Possibly looping over this check as well?

Comment: `if($('#inner').length) { // exists } else { // not }`

Comment: This question sounds like you've over-simplified your actual problem; why do you feel `DOMNodeInserted`, or `MustationObservers`, were the relevant solutions? Are you working with dynamic content in some way? What element do you want to check exists? For removing elements there are many ways to go, whether using jQuery or plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('#outer #inner').remove(); // Which for IDs shortens to $('#inner').remove()
```

or

```
$('#outer').empty();
```

Second question... check if an element exists:

```
if ($('#inner').length){
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: In your line, `if($('#inner').length)` length returns the length of the element? So should I check if that is > 0?

Comment: @Jared: `if (anythingNotFalse)` will match non-zero values. You do not need to compare explicitly against 0

Comment: @Jared if length is returned.. that means element is present.. you don't have to do `>0`..  Also it will return `1` because its a Id selector and `id's` must be unique in your HTML.. Even if you have duplicate ids it still returns 1 only

Answer (score 2):

if you don't get your answer please let me know.

[remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```js
$("#inner").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```